# Solve $ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} \cos x + \frac{dy}{dx} \sin x - 2y \cos^3 x = 2\cos^5x $ by a suitable transformation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider $ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} \cos x + \frac{dy}{dx} \sin x - 2y \cos^3 x = 2\cos^5x  $.

By a suitable transformation, reduce this equation to a second order linear differential equation with constant coefficients.

My try:

$$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} \cos x + \frac{dy}{dx} \sin x - 2y \cos^3 x = 2\cos^5x  \\ \Rightarrow \frac{\frac{d(\frac{dy}{dx})}{dx} \cos x - \frac{dy}{dx} \frac{d(\cos x)}{dx} }{\cos^2x} -2y \cos^3 x = 2\cos^5x  \\ \Rightarrow \frac{d\left( \frac{\frac{dy}{dx}}{\cos x} \right)}{dx} - 2y\cos^3x = 2\cos^5x$$
Unable to get rid of $\sin x$ or $\cos x$ terms from the coefficients.

Comment: I suppose that the transformation would be $x=f(t)$ and the problem is "just" to find $f(t)$.

Comment: Hi Claude! I didn't noticed your comment before posting my answer. I should have let the OP "just" find $f(t)$ instead of giving the hint. Cheers !

Comment: Hi, my question is, finding the transformation, is a totally trial and guessing effort, or there is any rule/intuition? I am not an expert here, trying to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} \cos x + \frac{dy}{dx} \sin x - 2y \cos^3 x = 2\cos^5x  $$
HINT :

The change of variable $\quad t=\sin(x)\quad$ leads to :
$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}-2y=2(1-t^2)$$
Solving leads to :
$$y=c_1e^{\sqrt{2}\:t}+c_2e^{-\sqrt{2}\:t}+t^2$$

Comment: Thank you Claude Leibovici  and JJacquelin. I am able to solve it now. Before posting this question, I tried many other transformations like v = y cosx, y/cosx etc. What is the intuition / rule behind selecting this transformation t = sin x ?

Comment: Do you know "the principle of least effort"? Before trying transformations involving $x$ and $y$ together, better try transformations involving $y$ only or $x$ only. And before trying complicated functions first try the simplest functions, for example $t=\cos(x)$ or $\sin(x)$.